# I ..... him since we met a year ago

Tags: present-perfect

> I  ..... him since we met a year ago.

options:

a) didn't see b)haven't seen c)hadn't seen

MyApproach:

Here,I am confused between didn't see VS haven't seen

> Also,Which Tense usage is used in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a** won't work with *since*, but both **b** and **c** will:

> I wonder what Joe Blow is doing. I haven't seen him since we met a year ago.
>   I ran into Joe Blow last night. I hadn't seen him since we met a year ago.

Comment: Hats off to you, Sir! Today I come to know that 'did' cannot work with 'since'.

Comment: @RuchirM Same here +1 for all the great knowledge we get from Sir.

Answer (score 1):

It should be (b) because you are saying what happened in a time span from the point "met" up to now, which is october 2014 to october 2015.

(C) is also possibe, but the time span starts from the point "met" until a later point of time but earlier than "now". For example, from october 2014 to june 2015.

Comment: How do you know in this Example "I ran into Joe Blow last night. I hadn't seen him since we met a year ago"  that ( the time span starts from the point "met" until a later point of time but earlier than "now) or I am gonna judge that? I use past perfect tense because the action has already happened before certain moment in the past.

Comment: @justintakro Perfects have "relative" tense; that is, the named action takes place at a time before the 'Reference Time' you are talking about. In the Joe Blow passage, "last night" in the preceding sentence defines the Reference Time for the past perfect. See [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §[3.1 Grammatical meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32).

Comment: Agree with @stoneyb